# MailGun (Binary Data Attachment)

Tags: mailgun

any examples of sending an email using mail gun with attachment in binary data?

Using this API Request https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{Domain}/messages

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: My API went through, i received the test email. However the attachments is not included. I'm using outsystem to develop mobile application. This platform only allow api request. Hence, i looking to post an api request that will include all the data needed to send the email

Comment: please make a proper question according to community rules: [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)